# Adjust alignment of formulas

Tags: align

How do I get the proportional sign and the bracket to align under each other? The whole thing always aligns to the left.

```
\begin{align}
f(\beta_i^{r,c},\alpha_{r,c}|n_{r,i},t_{c,i},(\lambda_1,\lambda_2) \text{oder} \lambda) \propto \\
\times \prod_{i=1}^{P} \prod_{c=1}^C ({\theta_{c,i}})^{t_{c,i}} \quad \bigg] \textbf{Individualdaten}
\end{align}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Could you give us, please, a better idea of what kind of alignment you'd like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that I understand your question properly.

If you want the proportional sign and the bracket to be aligned, you can try this (though I don't really like the way of this alignment):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
f(\beta_i^{r,c},\alpha_{r,c}|n_{r,i},t_{c,i},(\lambda_1,\lambda_2) \text{oder} \lambda) &\propto \\
\times \prod_{i=1}^{P} \prod_{c=1}^C ({\theta_{c,i}})^{t_{c,i}} \quad &\;\;\bigg] \textbf{Individualdaten}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, thats exactly what I was looking for. Why do you not like this way of alignement. Is there a more elegant way?

Comment: @Mucteam **I am very happy to hear that my answer is helpful to you.** Well, to me, I will remove the `\quad`, or make the space smaller instead :)) Personally I don't like too much space in mathematical formula, so **personally** I don't _really_ like this way of alignment :))

Comment: @DũngVũ The type of writing in LaTeX according to my modest point of view is completely personal.

Comment: @Sebastiano I agree.

Answer (score 1):

Following the Sigur's comment you can have other two alternative mode:

**1st form:**

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{aligned}
&f(\beta_i^{r,c},\alpha_{r,c}\mid n_{r,i},t_{c,i},(\lambda_1,\lambda_2) \text{ oder } \lambda) \propto  \\
& \times \prod_{i=1}^{P} \prod_{c=1}^C ({\theta_{c,i}})^{t_{c,i}} \quad \bigg] \mathbf{Individualdaten}
\end{aligned}
\]
\end{document}
```

**2nd form:**

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{aligned}
f(\beta_i^{r,c},\alpha_{r,c}\mid n_{r,i},t_{c,i},(\lambda_1,\lambda_2) \text{ oder } \lambda)&\propto  \\
& \times \prod_{i=1}^{P} \prod_{c=1}^C ({\theta_{c,i}})^{t_{c,i}} \quad \bigg] \mathbf{Individualdaten}
\end{aligned}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd use `\mid` instead of `|`. Also, blank spaces around `\text{ oder }`

Comment: @Mucteam We're all here to help you.

Comment: @Sigur I accept your suggestion.

Comment: @sigur I added them as well.